# best strategy to upgrade mongo 2dsphere index version with minimum performance impact

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-performance

We have recently upgraded from **mongo 3.0 to 3.2**
The application uses 2dsphere index heavily which is still at version 2.0.
We want to upgrade this **2dshpere index version to 3.0** to avail performance benefits that comes with it.

But the collection on which this needs to be done has **more than 10 Million nodes** and the application is a heavy traffic application that we can't afford to impact for long.

What should be our strategy to get this done with minimum impact on performance on real time traffic queries.

**Suggested solution:**

```
1) Create new 2dshpere index in background with version 3.0
2) After above is done, remove old 2dsphere index
```

Please suggest the best possible solution for the same or above is the best one can do for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my own answer as what we used worked well for us.
Would love to hear a better answer if any.

We first created version 3 index in background. So that both the indexes are there on parallel.

```
 db.goibibocms_nodes.createIndex({"fieldname":"2dsphere","background":1,"version":3},{"2dsphereIndexVersion":3})
```

Then we dropped the version 2 index.

```
 db.goibibocms_nodes_v2.dropIndex("old index name")
```

And it went off well without any performance downgrade when these index creation and drop was taking place.

Comment: I'm not sure how you were able to do this, MongoDB won't let you create 2 indexes with the same spec. You'll see the message `"all indexes already exist"`, even if the 2dsphereIndexVersion is different.

Comment: we were able to do this, what is the version of mongodb you are using ?